# Windows Phone 7 not reading dutch localization strings

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am trying to localize an app in Dutch, but the emulator doesn't seem to pick up and recognize the Dutch versions of my resource strings.

I have a base Strings.resx file with the english translations. Then, I have Strings.nl.resx with the Dutch translations. I also have Strings.es.resx, Strings.fr.resx, and Strings.it.resx.

When I change the emulator's language to Spanish, French, or Italian, it picks up those translations, but when I switch to Dutch, it uses the English translations. Am I using the right character code for the Dutch translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone 7 only supports English, French, Italian, German and Spanish at the moment.

When you choose the display language in the emulator, the choices are "Deutsch, English (UK), English (US), Espanol, Francais, Italiano" (plus the accents that I'm too lazy to type in).

Basically, I don't think you should be trying to localize the application to Dutch at the moment. I dare say a future revision of the platform will include more languages.

Having said that, you can set the "region format" to Dutch... I'm not sure how that's represented in the `CultureInfo`... I'll investigate.

EDIT: I've just tried setting my language to English (UK) but my region format to Dutch (Netherlands). I end up with a `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` of "nl-NL" but a `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` of "en-GB". I believe it's the latter which is used to load resources by default. So you probably *could* explicitly load the resources based on the `CurrentCulture` instead, but I suspect it's not a good idea.

Comment: That's odd, I am loading resources based on CurrentCulture and not CurrentUICulture. I think this was what the xna localization sample did, but I couldn't check since the samples were down last time I tried. I will repeat your experiment and see if I can investigate further - this may just be a WP7 bug too.

Answer (score 0):

nl is the right code but I wonder if it's due to Dutch not being a supported language.
Devices also won't be available in The Netherlands so it begs the question why you have the translation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Dutch is currenty just not supported. I made the foolish mistake of setting the AssemblyCulture of my app to nl.NL and then the phone (both developer prototype hardware and the emulator) would simply not even load the application). Nothing we can do, until a version of the OS (and Zune, markplace, etc.) comes out that actually supports Dutch. Which could be a while yet. Only official news so far is "medio 2011", which could basically mean the Q3/Q4 boundary of 2011, even though I hope it'll be much sooner.

For now my only app in the Marketplace shows Dutch content, but is localized in English, German and Spanish. If current culture string doesn't start with "nl" there's a button giving information about the actual downloaded content being in Dutch and not getting translated. That was enough to get it accepted into marketplace. The Dutch resources are in there though, so I hope I don't turn out the need to resubmit it just to get the Dutch version to show up on Dutch devices when they appear. Will have to wait for that, though.